# Replace x-axis index of imshow with frequency (kHz)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have following plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 1000
t = np.arange(0, 0.1, 1/fs)
N = len(t)
f_bin = fs / N
f = np.arange(0, fs, f_bin)
X = [np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 100 * t)), np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 200 * t)), np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 300 * t))]
M = np.absolute(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(M[:,:len(M[0,:]) // 2], cmap='viridis', aspect=1)
clb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
clb.ax.set_title("Magnitude")
ax.set_xlabel(f"Index (f[{round(100/f_bin)}] = {f[round(100/f_bin)]} Hz)")
ax.set_ylabel("# FFT")
ax.set_title(f"Built-in FFT")
plt.show()
```

which results in

[image]

Is there a (nice) solution to transform the "Index" into the actual "frequency bin" by using `f_bin` and `f`

[image]

I hope I haven't overlooked some already existing solutions in `Stack Overflow`.

Comment: You may want to read the Imshow's docs about [extent](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html#:~:text=extentfloats%20(left%2C%20right%2C%20bottom%2C%20top)%2C%20optional). Also [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html#explicit-extent).

Answer (score 1):

You can set new values for your xtick labels with `ax.set_xticklabels`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 1000
t = np.arange(0, 0.1, 1/fs)
N = len(t)
f_bin = fs / N
f = np.arange(0, fs, f_bin)
X = [np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 100 * t)), np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 200 * t)), np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 300 * t))]
M = np.absolute(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(M[:,:len(M[0,:]) // 2], cmap='viridis', aspect=1)
clb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
clb.ax.set_title("Magnitude")
ax.set_xlabel(f"Frequency (kHz)")
ax.set_ylabel("# FFT")
ax.set_title(f"Built-in FFT")
ax.set_xticklabels([x/100 for x in ax.get_xticks()])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but results in `UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator`

Comment: This worked

`label_format = '{:,.0f}'
left, right = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
ax.set_xlim(left, right)
ax.set_xticklabels([label_format.format(f[int(abs(x))]) for x in ax.get_xticks()])`


Thank again :)

Comment: I guess some other part of your code caused the error? The solution works for me on the provided example. Anyway, glad you could make it work!

Comment: Good answer, but you should be using `fftfreq` to establish the spectral axis.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to showing 2D data like this while setting the axes, you should use `pcolormesh`. In this case, your x values are set by `f/1000` and your y values are enumerated by the number of rows in `M` (in this case: 3). Assuming you still want a fat plot, you can set the aspect ratio to achieve that. I also changed the y-ticks to just be the y values.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

fs = 1000
t = np.arange(0, 0.1, 1/fs)
f_bin = fs/len(t)
f = np.arange(0, fs, f_bin)
X = [np.fft.fft(np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t)),
     np.fft.fft(np.sin(2*np.pi*200*t)),
     np.fft.fft(np.sin(2*np.pi*300*t))]
M = np.absolute(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

s = np.s_[:, :len(M[0, :]) // 2]
x = f[s[1]]/1000
y = np.arange(M.shape[0])

p = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, M[s], cmap="viridis")
fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax, label="Magnitude")

ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_aspect(10*y.max()/fs)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency [kHz]")
ax.set_ylabel("# FFT")
ax.set_title("Built-in FFT")
fig.show()
```

[image]